# How do I use a bipod? (Marksmen DLC)

Tags: arma-3

I know there is an old question from 2013 before the Marksmen DLC came out. Now that it is out, how do I use a bipod equipped onto a weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's C by default

but it depends.

Comment: Depends on what?  If you have more information, share it! :)

Comment: The answer is obvious, depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just press C, when a bipod is attached, as long as the rifle is lined up with something, Ie a windowsill. If you go prone and press C you will see. See?